# .js, setInterval, .load(), clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am never exactly sure when ajax-loaded.html is going to be generated (could be 1 second or 10 seconds), so I use setInterval to constantly call example_ajax_request(). That way when it does become available it shows up (within a second).

**Question-** How do I call myStopFunction() so that when example_ajax_request() actually does load ajax-loaded.html, setInterval stops?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example-placeholder">
<p>Placeholding text</p>
</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){example_ajax_request()},1000);
    function example_ajax_request() {
        $('#example-placeholder').html('<p><img src="ajax-loader.gif"  /></p>');
        $('#example-placeholder').load("ajax-loaded.html");
    }

    function myStopFunction(){
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you place that in a setInterval! that makes absolutely no sense. Calling it over and over and over won't make it finish any faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the load callback to clear the interval.

```
$('#example-placeholder').load("ajax-loaded.html", function () {
   myStopFunction();
});
```

**Polling every second is bad and You should use the `error` callback to retry with a retryCount.**

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski And it does kill the load() routine by killing the `setInterval`

Comment: This isn't working. Specifically, the loading gif fires up when the page loads, but even when ajax-loaded.html is later generated, the loading gif keeps circling (no content is ever loaded)...

Comment: @Chris We need more information to look into what you are talking about. The above is to just let you know that there is a callback function which will be called after the `.load` is completed.

Comment: Oh, ok... Ill dig in then from here. ALSO- do you by any chance have a link where I can learn the better way to accomplish this (using error callback)? Thank you for your time on this.

Comment: @Chris cool. Try it from here http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ <-- Contains list of ajax functions that jQuery offers.